# node js elasticsearch geo_distance not working

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I want to search for places within 2 km between elasticsearch indexes, but it didn't work. What is the problem?

```
await client
.search({
  index: "products",
  query: {
    bool: {
      must: {
        match_all: {},
      },
      filter: {
        geo_distance: {
          distance: "2km",
          location: {
            lat: 36.561139369367346,
            lon: 31.96256160036761,
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
})
.then((res) => console.log("response", res))
.catch((err) => console.log("err", err));
```

Comment: Can you provide more details with your issue? Are you getting errors? Are no results returned? What is not working?